# How can I make the MATLAB Satellite Simulation Viewer stop update graphics faster?

Tags: matlab

So I'm running a simulation of an ISS orbit in matlab to see how much groundstation link time our mission will have. I'm using the matlab satellite scenario viewer everything about my code seems to work. But, as soon as the viewer opens it begins "loading graphics." I've let it run for about 15 minutes before and it doesn't seem to progress or at least I would have expected it to load by then.

I'm attaching my code here to see if maybe what I'm doing is going to take an exceptionally long time but I'm not sure that anything in my code is the problem

```
starttime = datetime(2022,07,20,0,00,00);
endtime = datetime(2022,07,21,0,00,00);

sc = satelliteScenario(starttime,endtime,10000);
POLAR = satellite(sc,"ISSTLE.txt");
show(POLAR)
groundTrack(POLAR,"LeadTime",20^10);
```